# Normalizing histograms?

Tags: c++, video, opencv, histogram

What is normalizing histograms? When and why would I use it? What are its advantages?

I don't understand the concept at all- when I try to apply it to my histogram, when I use back projection, I don't get any results.

Could someone give me a non-technical explanation of normalization?

I am using OpenCV

PS: Don't send me to wikipedia- I don't understand the Wikipedia Page

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple, actually. A normalized histogram is one in which the sum of the frequencies is exactly 1. Therefore, if you express each frequency as a percentage of the total, you get a normalized histogram.

What is the use of a normalized histogram? Well, if you studied probability and/or statistics, you might know that one property required for a function to be a probability distribution for a random variable is that the total area under the curve is 1. That's for continuous-variable functions. For discrete functions, the requirements is that the sum of all values of the function is 1. So a normalized histogram can be thought of a probability distribution function which shows how probable each of the values of your random variable is.

Comment: Thanks for answering

I understood what is it perfectly, but I still don't get its use.

What exactly is its use in image processing? I am more focused on its image use than its mathematical use.

Thanks again.

Comment: I work in medical imaging software, and in that context an image histogram helps doctors and operators to see where most of the pixels are so that they can adjust brightness and contrast in order to enhance, say, bone tissue or muscular tissue, as needed